# search text in Emacs evil mode

Tags: emacs, full-text-search, evil-mode

C-s works fine in searching text in Emacs evil mode, but if I want to use vim shortcuts for text searching, / works for the first matching in searching forward, but type / again does not go to the next matching position as in vim does. So my question is, what is the shortcut to move to the next matching position if using vim shortcuts? Retype /[matching-text-pattern] surely works but too inconvenient.

Thanks!

Comment: never tried evil-mode, but vi's "next match" is 'n'. try it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I do search in evil-mode:

**/**[matching-text-pattern]

**RET**

**n** for next match

**N** for previous match

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need.

Answer (score 7):

Evil has two 'search modules': `isearch`, which is more similar to Emacs' search, and `evil-search`, which is more similar to Vim's search. Switching to the `evil-search` module should give the behavior you want:

```
(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)
```

Comment: Actually both two search shortcuts work at mean time. I know isearch works fine but want to stick to vim search shortcuts, so I asked the question. Thanks for the answer!